# Why do I get a non-zero intercept using the lasso even though I centered the response?

Tags: lasso, normalization, standardization, high-dimensional

It's my understanding that if I center $y$, the intercept should be 0. However, when using `glmnet`, I get a non-zero intercept doing this:

```
lasso_model = glmnet(x=bodyfat$x,y=bodyfat$y-mean(bodyfat$y),intercept=TRUE,alpha = 1,lambda = 1.5)
```

The intercept is given as $-45.53019$, but shouldn't it be 0 because I've taken the mean from the response?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not in general the case that centering $y$ produces an intercept of zero. Centering $y$ means that the average value of the centered variable is zero, but the intercept is the predicted value for $y$ when $x=0$.

To illustrate, try plotting `bodyfat$y` against `bodyfat$x`, and then plotting `bodyfat$y - mean(bodyfat$y)` against `bodyfat$x`, and think about what the axes mean. For example, does it even make sense for $x$ to be zero? If $x$ is height and $y$ is weight, then the intercept is the predicted weight (or difference from the mean in weight) at a height of zero.

Comment: I would only add: If you centre both $x$ *and* $y$, you will get an intercept of exactly $0$.